# Integers minimizing sum of square roots given a sum constraint

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, proof-writing

Let $n$, $m<n$, and $l<n$ be three integers. Minimize the following sum: $\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{n_i}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m n_i = n$, $n_i\leq l$ and $n_i\in \mathbb{N}$. Could we prove that
$$ n_1=..=n_k=l,\;\; n_{k+1}=q,\;\;n_{k+2}=..=n_m=0$$ is the optimal solution, where $k$ and $q$ are given by the Euclidien division $n=k\;l+q$.

Comment: Do you mean to **maximize** the sum? Because the sum is **not** minimized when $n_1=\dots=n_m=n/m$. Note that $\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{4}\ge \sqrt{13}+\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}$.

Comment: Thanks for noting. I have forgotten another constraint, but good point. The question was edited.

Comment: No, still not true. Follow up the patter from Mike Earnest post, put $n=kl$ and then you wouldget $$k\sqrt{l} >\sqrt{k(l-1)} + k-1$$ which is true since on the left the coefficient of $k$ is 1 and on the right it is $\sqrt{l}$. In words, if l is large enough the inequality holds.

Comment: @Salcio. The term $n_1=k(l-1)$ of the right side of the inequality may not respect the constraint $n_1\leq l$.

Comment: Sorry, have not noticed that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, show that if the list $(n_1, \dots ,n_m)$ has two entries $n_i$ and $n_j$ for which
$$
\ell>n_i\ge n_j>0,
$$
then the list is not minimal. Proving this intermediate inequality is helpful:
$$
\sqrt{n_i+1}+\sqrt{n_j-1}< \sqrt n_i +\sqrt{n_j}.
$$
This shows that the list obtained by replacing $n_i$ with $n_i+1$ and $n_j$ with $n_j-1$ has a smaller sum of square roots. Therefore, an optimal list can have at most one entry which is neither $0$ nor $\ell$. Let us call this entry $q$. If we let $k$ be the number of occurrences of $\ell$, we have $n=k\ell+q$, as required.